# Why a lambda cannot make the enclosing function return?

Tags: function, lambda, kotlin, anonymous-function

I'm quite new to Kotlin. I hit this part while I was going over the docs:

> "a lambda cannot return from the enclosing function" (unless it's inlined).

So, this doesn't work;

```
fun foo() {
    ordinaryFunction {
        return // ERROR: cannot make `foo` return here
    }
}
```

I wonder why it works that way?

The only thing I can think of it's dangerous since there might be some extra stuff the enclosing function might be doing after the lambda execution. But I'm not sure that's the reason because you can overcome this by using qualified returns or using `inline` keyword. So, that kind of implies there's a technical reason behind it (apart from any usability/safety reasons) like the compiler cannot figure out where to return unless it's labeled or inlined.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here that [non-local](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) returns [can't be done on the JVM](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/3yybyf/returning_from_lambda_functions/).
If you want to return from lambda (local return) you can add label `@ordinaryFunction`:

```
fun foo() {
    ordinaryFunction {
        return@ordinaryFunction
    }
}
```

[Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) say:

> If we need to return from a lambda expression, we have to label it and qualify the `return`. Oftentimes it is more convenient to use implicit labels: such a label has the same name as the function to which the lambda is passed. In our case it is `@ordinaryFunction`.

Comment: It's not about "how" to do it. It's more about the dynamics under the hood like "why" the compiler doesn't allow it. After all, they're all "functions types", right.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else can probably explain this better but in pretty much any programming language, when you call a function, a new entry is created on top of *the stack*. The stack keeps information about the arguments that the function was called with and the place you should return to when the function completes.

Kotlin doesn't have a feature that lets you return from multiple function calls in one return, so you have to return from each function call manually.

When you inline a function the machine code that would normally execute in a separate subroutine is now copy pasted to the function call site instead. That's why return from an inline function actually returns from the function that called the inlined lambda.

Comment: I see your point but then how come it works with anonymous functions but not with lambdas? Lambda also creates a function type.

Comment: In an anonymous function, the `return` is returning from the anonymous function, not from the enclosing function.  (The rule is that `return` always returns from the nearest `fun`, unless you qualify it like `return@something`.)

Answer (score 0):

> there might be some extra stuff the enclosing function might be doing after the lambda execution.

The problem is the other way around: the lambda can "escape" from the enclosing function's scope and end up executing after the function returns. E.g. consider

```
fun foo() {
    Thread(Runnable { 
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        return
    })
}
```

Or just

```
 fun foo() = // lambda
```

In either case it makes no sense for the lambda to return from `foo`, does it? And the compiler doesn't know if your `ordinaryFunction` lets the lambda escape `foo`'s scope unless it's inline.

> you can overcome this by using qualified returns

That's not really overcoming, that's just not returning from the enclosing function.